# Why my NSPanel doesn't have background of gray color as normal?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nspanel

My app has an icon in the menubar. A `NSPanel` shows up when I click the icon. But why does the `NSPanel` not have a background color like other having gray background `NSWindow`? My `NSPanel`'s background looks like transparent.  My `NSPanel` comes from a `.xib` file. My code as follows:

```
(void)openPanel
{

NSLog(@"openPanel");

NSWindow *panel = self.panelController.window;

NSRect rect = [[[NSApp currentEvent] window] frame];
NSLog(@"rect.origin.x = %f",rect.origin.x);
NSLog(@"rect.origin.y = %f",rect.origin.y);
NSLog(@"rect.size.width = %f",rect.size.width);
NSLog(@"rect.size.height = %f",rect.size.height);
[panel setFrame:NSMakeRect(rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y-100, 200, 100) display:YES];
[NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:NO];
[panel makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil];

isPanelVisible = YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally NSPanels are semi-transparent. See [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/nspanel_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for more information. If you don't want the semi-transparency you could change NSPanel in IB under custom class from NSPanel to NSWindow.